# The pdf report with manual tagging throws EmptyStackException

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have spring webapp where I am using JasperReports to generate some basic database query reports and exporting into pdf.

I have tried programmatically adding tags instead of using jrxml, with dynamic-jasper and that runs into different issue. My jrxml file is almost a copy of tabular-report.jrxml example from Jaspersoft Studio. Let me know if you need to look at something else to figure this out, any help is appreciated at this point.

Found this but it has no solution: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1112221/error-manulal-tagging-table-pdf-export

Here is my jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ....>
    <style>....
    </style>
    <queryString>
        This works, deleted because its sensitive.
    </queryString>
    <field name="last_login" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="first_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="middle_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="last_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IAL" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="xid" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="45">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="reportTitleStyle" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="595" height="30">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h1" value="full"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[User Login Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="subTitleStyle" positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="595" height="15">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2" value="full"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA["This report was generated at " + new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="30">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="defaultHeaderStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="95" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.table" value="start"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.th" value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.rowspan" value="2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Last Login"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="defaultHeaderStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="95" y="0" width="83" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.th" value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.rowspan" value="2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["First Name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="defaultHeaderStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="178" y="0" width="59" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.th" value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.rowspan" value="2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Middle Name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="defaultHeaderStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="237" y="0" width="83" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.th" value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.rowspan" value="2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Last Name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="defaultHeaderStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="320" y="0" width="35" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.th" value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.rowspan" value="2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["IAL"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="defaultHeaderStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="355" y="0" width="59" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.th" value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.rowspan" value="2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["XID"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="defaultHeaderStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="414" y="0" width="141" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.th" value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.rowspan" value="2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Email"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Immediate">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="15">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.tr" value="full"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="timeStampColumnStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="95" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{last_login}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="columnStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="95" y="0" width="83" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{first_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="columnStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="178" y="0" width="59" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{middle_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="columnStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="237" y="0" width="83" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{last_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="columnStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="320" y="0" width="35" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="columnStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="355" y="0" width="59" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{xid}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="columnStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="414" y="0" width="141" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.table" value="end"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The error:

```
java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporterTagHelper.createTrStartTag(JRPdfExporterTagHelper.java:664)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporterTagHelper.createStartTags(JRPdfExporterTagHelper.java:589)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporterTagHelper.startElement(JRPdfExporterTagHelper.java:499)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1241)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1210)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:1074)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:691)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
```

Comment: I have removed 4 lines from the error-trace pointing to my classes.

Comment: What version of JasperReports are you using?

Comment: I am using 6.13.0<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the `net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.table=end` property which is set on an element in the detail band in your report.  The detail band repeats for each record in the query result, so setting `net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.table=end` in the detail band doesn't make sense.

The property should be set on an element that prints only once at the end of the table/page, for instance in the page footer band:

```
<pageFooter>
    <band height="1">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="1">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.table" value="end"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression>""</textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I didnt need a footer for my report so I didnt add one, initially. I now have the tags I wanted in my pdf report but every tag has <text> tag added under them. Do you know a way to remove these extra tags or change it to <p>?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without changing the JasperReports code yourself.